# При наведении на кнопку, меняю фон, как сделать чтобы и <p> в кнопке тоже менялся вместе с ним css

Tags: javascript, css, button, hover

При наведении на кнопку, при помощи  hover меняю фон, как сделать чтобы и  `<p>` тоже менялся одновременно с фоном. И возможно ли при помощи css это сделать?

```
<button class="btn" id="fonts"><p>Кнопка</p></button>
```

css

```
.btn {
    background: transparent none;          
}
.btn p {        
    color: #FFCC00;
}
.btn:hover {
    background:#FED802;
}
.btn p:hover {
    color: #004a80;
}
```

Заранее спасибо и извиняюсь, если вопрос дурацкий, но гугл уже устал.
http://jsfiddle.net/22rtnr8u/

Comment: У тебя ж еще id есть, что он присваевает? он же выше по иерархии идет, если в нем указан цвет шрифта - у тебя не получится ничего)

Comment: мб средствами JS решается? к сожалению мои знания в нем на уровне "Hello world".

Comment: в css в самом начале точки не хватает

Comment: используйте span вместо p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.btn {
  background: transparent none;
}
.btn p {
  color: #FFCC00;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #FED802;
}
.btn:hover p {
  color: #004a80;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="fonts">
  <p>Кнопка</p>
</button>
```

Comment: вот тут не работает http://jsfiddle.net/22rtnr8u/

Comment: спс, такое не доглядеть , пора спать